# Timer in Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, system.timers.timer

I want use one Timer in my controller to do a specific job.

Below is the code

```
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {

        private readonly System.Timers.Timer _checkTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        public readonly int CheckTimerInterval = 10 * 30 * 1000;

        public ProductsController()
        {
            _checkTimer.Elapsed += CheckTimerElapsed;
            _checkTimer.Interval = this.CheckTimerInterval;
            _checkTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void CheckTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        { 
          //Do the processing
        }
     }
```

But the problem is when ever I call controller a new instance of Timer is created.

I want only one timer instance.Can you please help me to achieve this?

I know using Timer in controller is not a good idea but I do not have other option.I use this controller to assign Requests to an temporary User.In Timer I need to get all jobs and assign it to actual User.

Comment: *"I know using Timer in controller is not a good idea"* - Correct, it's not.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is not a good idea. The only way  I can see this working is if you add the timer to a dependency injection container as a singleton or making it static somewhere else - perhaps wrapped in a service

Comment: This is an XY problem. Rather than asking "I know this is bad but how can I make it work", explain why you need it in the first place and we can help you come up with an alternative that *isn't* bad.

Comment: I use this controller to assign Requests to an temporary User.In Timer I need to get all jobs and assign it to actual User.

Comment: `I use this controller to assign Requests to an temporary User.In Timer I need to get all jobs and assign it to actual User.` <= that still provides no context. What is the business use case. What is it your are trying to achieve. What is a temporary user, what is a job, why assign jobs to users, what does a timer have to do with jobs or users, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your same code in a static class under one method. Then call that method under Global.asax.cs file under your Application_Start() method

```
public static class GlobalValues
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer bomreporttimer;
    public static void StartScrapBom()
    {
        bomreporttimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        bomreporttimer.Elapsed += Bomreporttimer_Elapsed;
        bomreporttimer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 15;
        bomreporttimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs file

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalValues.GlobalValues.StartScrapBom();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this in the first place, try to find the problem you are trying to solve and try other options of solving it.

But in any case, you need to have a static instance of the timer, so you can simply make it static, you can use IOC as well to do that. It might be better to place it in a place like `startup` or `global_asax` kind of code, to indicate it's global and static. Btw, you need to think about threads as well, so may be make it a singeton.

Again, don't do this at all.